# Increment array element during declaration using variable issue

Tags: linux, bash

So yes, normally you would increment an array using a for loop or a similar method, but in this scenario, that's not possible as I am already in a loop and need to only set one value in the array and move on. Here's the code:

```
n=1
cat databases/$IPS | grep -v \# | while read LINE; do
  ENDPOINT[$n]="`echo $LINE | cut -d":" -f1`";
  echo "TESTING: ${ENDPOINT[$n]}"
  let n++
done
```

So the while loop will read several lines from a flat file database and pull the first colon separated value out which needs to be stored in the array. Things are just getting muddy from working on this project too long. I might have to just rethink this part.

So the official question is, without using another loop, how can increment elements using a variable so I can setup the array in the current while loop.

----- UPDATE -----

I know what im trying to do seems a little weird and unorthodox. So the while loop reads a database line by line. During the first iteration of the while loop, the database gets read and the first "cell" on the first row of the database gets stored to in the array as array element 1 (or could be 0, doesen't matter). The while loops then goes back for its second pass, and pulls the first cell of the second row in database and it needs to store it to the array under element 2. The loop continues to do this until the end of the database.

So I know how to read the contents of an array using a loop, but I have never set up an array using a loop. I cannot get the element number in the array to increment so that when the while loop does its next pass, it doesn't just keep overwriting array[1]

Does that help?

----- UPDATE -----

So it looks like this kinda works. The whole point of storing this database value in this array is because not only is it being used inside this while loop (Omitted irrelevant code). but I need to use these values elsewhere in the script.

cat databases/$IPS | grep -v # | while read LINE; do
  VAR="`echo $LINE | cut -d"|" -f1`";
  ENDPOINT[$n]="$VAR"
  echo "Heres the array variable: ${ENDPOINT[$n]}"
done

Problem still is though that it doesn't appear to be truly storing to the array. It's just overwriting the first element in the array. If I try to echo any of the lower array values somewhere in the script, the only one that comes up is the the value in array element 0 and its set to the last entry in the database.

Comment: What do you want to increment? You do not need a loop to increment an array element.

Comment: I don't understand the question at all, can you elaborate?

Comment: The array is getting updated, if you echo ${ENDPOINT[@]} in the loop the values are there, they get lost after the loop exits. Some sort of scope problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seems to be that you are executing a command, may be this is a separate process and the array gets lost when it completes

Do this instead:

```
n=1
endpoints=`grep -v \# databases/$IPS | cut -d":" -f1`
for i in $endpoints; do
  ENDPOINT[$n]=$i;
  echo "TESTING: ${ENDPOINT[$n]}"
  let n++
done
```

Comment: Excellent thank you, this ultimately ended up working in conjunction with my previous thought process. Sleep helps too. Got some rest, and then came back to look at the problem again. Everything is working now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't understand your question at 100%. I assume you can't get access to array elements outside of while loop.

That is because `while` is executed within `cat` command context, that is started as separate process. To get access to your array elements, you must set their values within the same bash context.

For example, you can use sed to get first of colon separated values and taking care of comments:

```
file_name=data

# extract values and put it into bash array
ENDPOINT=(`sed 's/[ \t]*#.*//g;s/^\([^:]*\):.*/\1/g' $file_name`)

echo "size: ${#ENDPOINT[@]}"
echo "readed data: ${ENDPOINT[@]}"
```

Also this variant is much very faster than `while read` loop, that have calls to another commands.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I really appreciate your suggestion, but I didn't get a chance to test it as I found another solution. Thank you very much though.